# PHP Warning: Illegal String Offset attributes

Tags: php, string, warnings, offset

Can someone help me out please. My error log is getting blown up by this error and I cannot figure out why.

PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'attributes' in xml.php on line 377

Here is the xml.php file > http://pastebin.com/SL8Kt7Zu

Comment: Check what `$v` contains by var_dumping it.

Comment: Please paste your code & results directly into the question, rather than posting to an outside service like pastebin.  The external code can go away at any time, and there is no version control over it like with SO questions.  Therefore, future readers will probably not be able to see the external code and thus this question will be useless or not make much sense. **StackOverflow is as much about future reference for others as it is about you getting your question answered today.**

Answer (score 0):

On the line 377 check if the index is set before trying to access it:

```
if(isset($v['attributes'])) {
```